# Render partial view (MVC) in bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to render a partial view in a bootstrap modal. I used this as a guide:

[Render mvc partial view inside modal](https://codemagik.wordpress.com/2015/04/07/render-mvc-partial-view-inside-bootstrap-modal-dialog/)

The thing is it works fine when using an actionlink, but I need to use a straight HTML achor:

```
<a id="myBtn" class="modal-link btn btn-warning" onclick="doSomething(this)" >DO IT</a>
```

When using this the modal doesn't show at all. This should be the same as a actionlink, or am I wrong?

The reason I use a html anchor and not razor syntax is that I use it with an custom ajax call to get some results with javascript, that I send to my controller.

My ajax call (doSomething()):

```
var data = [{ name: 'test', id: '123' }, { name: 'test2', id: '12334' }];

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: JSON.stringify({ theData: data }),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (data) {
         alert(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: What is your `doSomething()` function?

Comment: Updated description.

Comment: Your not doing anything in the `success` callback (except an alert). Does the method your calling return a partial view that you want do display in the modal? And if it is, you need something like `$(someElement).html(data); to update the DOM (and then probably call `$(yourModal).show();` to make it visible.

Comment: You are correct. Added both html and show and now it shows, but doesn't have any background color and it's very stretched like it doesn't use the bootstrap css at all.

Comment: Have you added the relevant class names?

Comment: See: http://imgur.com/a/xnUtJ, yes it has all the relevant class names on container, header, body and footer.

Comment: Impossible to tell without knowing your code and the html that is created. Suggest you create a simple fiddle to reproduce it.

Comment: Yeah I understand. Will try to get a example working in fiddle.